# Appium/Windows Application Driver timing out with UWP app

Tags: c#, selenium, uwp, appium

I'm testing a UWP app, following the examples here https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver. It seems like lately I've been getting a lot of

> Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver
>   server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/session timed out after 60
>   seconds.

As well as general slowness and taking forever to find UI elements (I've added several tests). Following the advice here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/z7QqtJLEwiw I tried increasing the time out to some large value like 10 minutes

```
var appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
appCapabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "6000");
appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", "AppIdGoesHere");

AppSession = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appCapabilities);
```

That doesn't work either.

I've seen a lot of questions related to WebDriver for this, but *none* relating to testing Windows 10 UWP apps. I'm also using a general C# unit test project type, since I have VS 2015 Pro, not Enterprise, which allows for the Coded UI test type.

Comment: I had similar problems with Appium for UWP. Tests were too unreliable so I removed UI tests from build flow altogether. The only solution I see is to wait for stable release of WinAppDriver and check again if situation is improved.